# How is this 'if' statement being used?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, boolean

Could someone help me understand how the 'if' statements are being used in this bit of code?  This is an exercise from the LearnStreet series of Python lessons: http://www.learnstreet.com/lessons/study/python#get-hint

I thought 'if' statements required a Boolean condition:  if X < Y, then do Z.  But I don't see how Booleans are a part of these 'if' statements.

```
def run():
     smiths = {"father": "Mike", "ex-wife" : "Mary", "children" : ["Bobby", "Susan"] }
     jones = {"mother": "Lucy", "ex-husband": "Peter", "children": ["Michelle", "Jeff", "Evan"]}
     family = {}
     for key in smiths:
         if key in family:
             family[key]+=smiths[key]
         else:
             family[key]=smiths[key]
     for key in jones:
         if key in family:
             family[key]+=jones[key]
         else:
             family[key]=jones[key]
     keysToDel = []
     for key in family:
         if 'ex' in key:
             keysToDel.append(key)
     print keysToDel
     for key in keysToDel:
         del family[key]
     return family
```

Comment: Read it like a natural language. "If x in y" can definitely be true or false, right? Here y would be a container and x would be an element.

Comment: `x < y` is just one type of expression that can return a Boolean value. `key in family` is another in Python; the `in` operator reports if the first argument is contained in the second, with the type of the second argument determining what "in" means.

Answer (score 1):

`if key in family:`

Here the key is an `element` and the `family` is an `container` or `sequence`

and you are trying to find the existence of the `key` in the `family`

this `if` statement returns `True` if the `key` is found in the `container` otherwise returns `False`

Comment: right, but family{} has NOTHING in it to start with, so shouldn't the initial if statement return FALSE?

Comment: @user2799714, yes the initial `if` will return `False`, since the family is `{}`, and in the corresponding `else` initializes it !

Answer (score 1):

These are boolean expressions, as [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) is a Python keyword returning `True` or `False` depending on whether left operand is contained in the collection denoted by the right operand. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

> The operators in and not in test for collection membership. x in s evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s. The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for many other object types to support membership tests without being a sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support membership testing.

Answer (score 0):

They are boolean conditions. Boolean conditions don't *have* to look like "if X < Y", that's just an example. A boolean condition is simply anything that evaluates to true or false. "key in family" evaluates to true if the value of "key" is in the list "family", and false otherwise.

Comment: Okay, so initially it evaluates to 'FALSE', but how does that make sense?  It looks like the keys of smiths will only be added to family{} if the statement evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: @user2799714 No, family is filled every time something isn't in it. "if in family, increment, else add to family"

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense.  "If this thing is NOT in this other thing, then go ahead and add it."  But I don't understand why the += was used.  Doesn't that mean "add Y to X so that X = X+Y"?

Comment: @user2799714, you are donig `X = X + Y` (family[key]+=smiths[key]) only when you find the key in the container, otherwise you are doing `X = Y` (family[key]=smiths[key])

Comment: What is the purpose of the += operator here?  It looks like the keys from smiths{} are being added to family{} when the if statement evaluates to TRUE, which doesn't make sense, because the if statement tests if smiths[key] are already in family{}.

Answer (score 0):

`if key in family`
means

`if the container "family" contains "key"`

In C-like languages it could be written something like

`if( family.contains(key) )`

Either family will contain key, or it won't.  So it's a boolean expression